# Naive box blur with OpenGL compute shader is very slow

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I'm used to doing image processing like blurring with fragment shaders, but I want to avoid the extra code necessary to set up rendering of a full-screen quad now by using compute shaders instead. I wrote a simple box blur implementation the following way:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image_write.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(512, 512, "Dummy", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    gladLoadGL();

    int width, height, channels;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("input.png", &width, &height, &channels, 4);

    GLuint inTexture;
    glGenTextures(1, &inTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, inTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    stbi_image_free(data);

    GLuint outTexture;
    glGenTextures(1, &outTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

    const char* shaderSource = R"glsl(
            #version 440 core

            layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;

            layout(rgba8, binding = 0) readonly restrict uniform image2D imageInput;
            layout(rgba8, binding = 1) writeonly restrict uniform image2D imageOutput;

            void main() {
                ivec2 pixelCoord = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);

                const int windowSize = 33;

                vec4 colorSum = vec4(0.0);
                float weightSum = 0.0;

                for (int x = pixelCoord.x - windowSize / 2; x <= pixelCoord.x + windowSize / 2; x++) {
                    for (int y = pixelCoord.y - windowSize / 2; y <= pixelCoord.y + windowSize / 2; y++) {
                        colorSum += imageLoad(imageInput, ivec2(x, y));
                        weightSum += 1.0;
                    }
                }

                imageStore(imageOutput, pixelCoord, colorSum / weightSum);
            }
        )glsl";

    GLuint computeShader = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(computeShader, 1, &shaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(computeShader);

    GLuint computeProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(computeProgram, computeShader);
    glLinkProgram(computeProgram);

    glUseProgram(computeProgram);
    glBindImageTexture(0, inTexture, 0, false, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA8);
    glBindImageTexture(1, outTexture, 0, false, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA8);

    double start = glfwGetTime();

    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(width * height * 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);
        glDispatchCompute(512, 512, 1);
        glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outTexture);
        glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer.data());
    }

    double end = glfwGetTime();

    std::cerr << "compute time: " << (end - start) << std::endl;

    stbi_write_png("output.png", width, height, 3, buffer.data(), 0);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

I know that this box blur implementation is not optimal, but I'm going to implement other filters like bilateral filters after this anyway.

When I implemented this as a fragment shader and rendered the output to a renderbuffer, I would get around 800 FPS with nearly the exact same shader code. I expected the compute shader to be similarly fast, but processing a 512x512 image this way takes half a second! I made sure that there is no initial slowdown in case the driver defers some operations by running the compute operation 20 times, but this results in a 20 second wall-clock time wait.

I admit that I'm not very familiar with the optimal way to determine global and local workgroup size, but this seems to be the approach most tutorials take. Having a workgroup for every pixel and some low amount of local workgroups like 2x2, 4x4 or 8x8. However, I found that using any local workgroup size higher than 1x1 resulted in even worse performance.

I also thought that the memory access might be the bottleneck, so I tried replacing the imageLoad with just adding a `vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` as a test, but this only reduces the run-time to around 150 ms, which is still unacceptable.

What could be causing my compute shader to be so slow?

Comment: Did you check that `glGetTexImage` isn't the bottleneck?

Comment: @BDL If I do almost nothing in the shader (1x1 kernel size), the run-time is just a millisecond.

Comment: In general: Having 1000+ texture lookups per invocation will be terrible slow. I'm actually less surprised that the compute shader takes 500ms than that a fragment shader approach should be that fast. Are you sure that you do the same amount of lookups in the fragment shader? Did you compare the result images of both approaches?

Comment: @BDL Many texture lookups is not really a special case. Direct volume renderers typically do 500+ lookups in a 3D texture per fragment and easily run with 60 FPS. Depth-of-field post-processing filters can also perform many reads per fragment.

Comment: @BDL I just did a test with a fragment shader that performs 66k texture lookups and that one takes 300ms.

Comment: 66k lookups per output pixel or in total? Your compute shader does around 285M lookups in total.

Comment: @BDL My fragment shader did 17B lookups in 300ms (filtering a 512x512 image with a 257x275 window).

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest a number of things to try.

1. Read from `sampler2D` with `texelFetch()` rather than from `image2D` with `imageLoad()`. This way you are benefiting from texture cache.
2. The local workgroup size should be a multiple of the warp/wavefront size of the hardware. For NVidia it's 32 and for AMD it's 64, so 8x8 local workgroup is a good choice. I know you've tried it and it made things worse, but combined with other suggestions it should help.
3. Consider fetching a rectangular region of pixels of size *wogkroup_dims + window_dims* into a shared array, and then reading from that array when doing the convolution. This way you are minimizing the number of expensive texture fetches, replacing them with cheaper shared memory access. When using this approach, it makes sense to go with an even larger local workgroup size, perhaps 16x16. This approach requires using GLSL `barrier()` and `memoryBarrierShared()` functions.

Comment: "*This way you are benefiting from texture cache.*" I'm pretty sure `imageLoad` operations are cached too.

Comment: @NicolBolas It looks like you are right. I replaced a `texelFetch()` with `imageLoad()` in some existing code, and the timings are indeed very similar.

Comment: @NicolBolas I did one more test replacing a texelFetch() with imageLoad() and this time I am seeing a small but measurable performance degradation. The FPS dropped from 57.6 to 56.2. It's a static volume-rendered scene, so I can measure FPS with high accuracy, and I did so multiple times. The `texelFetch()` being replaced wasn't in my ray tracer's main loop, so I imagine the potential performance difference is greater than the figure given.

Comment: I have tried `texelFetch` as well, but it makes not much of a difference. Also, my fragment shader experiments also used imageLoad instead of texelFetch and they reached 200+ FPS.

Answer (score 2):

try...

glDispatchCompute(32, 32, 1);

with

layout(local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16) in;

I am just figuring this stuff out too, and these settings work fastest for me
on a 512x512 image.

-cds